# Can't Access sObject 'type' Property

Tags: soap-api, c#

I am following a [Salesforce tutorial](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sample_create_call.htm) using Soap to create and modify Salesforce objects using C#.

I downloaded a WSDL from my org and have added it as a web reference in my project and I can successfully log into my sandbox, so I know to some extent my reference is working.

However, the problem I have now is that when I try to do something similar to the tutorial like:

```
var contact = new sObject();
contact.type = "Contact";
```

It seems like I am lacking permission to set the 'type' property of an sObject?

However I can just create a 'Contact' object straight from my Sfdc reference, so would it be preferable to just do that for this scenario? I any case if someone could explain why I can't seem to access sObject.type that would be appreciated as I want to make sure there is nothing wrong with my web reference in my project.

Comment: Documentation says to use ‘sObject contact = new sforce.sObject();’ instead of ‘new sObject();’. Give it a go!

Comment: Sure, but using 'var' and getting rid of the redundant 'sforce' qualifier shouldn't (and doesn't) make any difference here.

Comment: Have you tried it. Sometimes things work differently than we imagine.

Comment: Yes, the result is the same